# Pulling variable from one method to use in another

Tags: java, sql

I am currently trying to pull a string variable, `tableChoice`, from the `determineTable` method to use it in `exactWordMatch`.

My code:

```
public class DynamicQueryHandler {

    static String tableChoice;

    public static void determineTable() {

        String[] choices = { "Customer", "Department", "Employee", "Vehicle", "Works In" };
        String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose the table to search from",
                "Dealership Database", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, choices, choices[0]);
        if (input == choices[0])
            tableChoice = "CUSTOMER";
        if (input == choices[1])
            tableChoice = "DEPARTMENT";
        if (input == choices[2])
            tableChoice = "EMPLOYEE";
        if (input == choices[3])
            tableChoice = "VEHICLE";
        if (input == choices[4])
            tableChoice = "WORKS_IN";
    }

    public static void exactWordMatch() throws SQLException {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());

        String serverName = "server";
        String portNumber = "port";
        String sid = "sid";
        String url = "url" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + ":" + sid;
        String Result = "";
        String Header = "test header";

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "user", "pass");
        Statement statemet = connection.createStatement();
        System.out.println(tableChoice);
        ResultSet resultSet = statemet.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableChoice);
        resultSet.close();
        statemet.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

When I run the program, `tableChoice` is coming back as "`null`". I've tried making the `determineTable` function return the string `tableChoice` and that didn't work. I made the variable class-wide and that didn't work either. I'm not sure where to go from here. 
I want it to return the name of my SQL tables, so I can use it for an SQL query.

Changing it to:

```
public class DynamicQueryHandler {

    static String tableChoice;

    public static void determineTable() {

        String[] choices = { "Customer", "Department", "Employee", "Vehicle", "Works In" };
        String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose the table to search from",
                "Dealership Database", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, choices, choices[0]);
        if (input.equals(choices[0]))
            tableChoice = "CUSTOMER";
        if (input.equals(choices[1]))
            tableChoice = "DEPARTMENT";
        if (input.equals(choices[2]))
            tableChoice = "EMPLOYEE";
        if (input.equals(choices[3]))
            tableChoice = "VEHICLE";
        if (input.equals(choices[4]))
            tableChoice = "WORKS_IN";
    }
```

Still makes tableChoice null when calling it from exactWordMatch()

Comment: You are not comparing your `String`'s correctly, so `tableChoice` is always `null`. Use `String#equals`.

Comment: Compare the string using equals method and i don't about the case you are using in input. For that you can use equalsignorecase() to compare the strings with case insensitivity.

Comment: In your if statements instead of input == choices[0]; try input.equals(choices[0]); because that is way to compare strings

Comment: I tried it both ways, changing it to
if (input.equals(choices[0]))
   tableChoice.equals("CUSTOMER"); 
and changing it to just
if (input == choices[0])
   tableChoice.equals("CUSTOMER");

Comment: Use `.equals()` for the comparison of two `String`s, not the assignment of a `String`. You were assigning your `tableChoice` correctly. Just not doing the comparison correct.  `if (input.equals(choices[0])) tableChoice="CUSTOMER";`

Comment: I did that, and tableChoice is still null when I try to use it from the exactWordMatch function.

Comment: Try printing `tableChoice` at the end of your `determineTable`. What prints out? With the proper changes, I do not get `tableChoice` to be null.

Comment: You are clicking `OK` in your popup correct? Only way I get `null` is if I hit `Cancel`. Which you should also do a check for by the way.

Comment: I am clicking ok in my popup. I just tried printing tableChoice at the end of determineTable, and it didn't print anything. Is the code just not going through my if statement?

Comment: I figured out what my problem was. I was calling the wrong function from another class. I apologize for the inconvenience. Thank you very much for your help.